# How to count CSS colors used in project/file

Tags: css, architecture

I remember seeing one presentation on CSS architecture on the net and I recall the author mentioning that in some projects she had worked on they had around 100s to 1K different CSS colors codes.

Such (unwanted) diversity creates a maintenance problem since one must debate with himself which of the many shades of something to use.

Having some sort of branding guideline and using CSS variables seem to be the go-to solution, but first, one needs to know what are the colors, where they occur and how many times, as to be able to reconcile it.

I wonder how could I get such a report from my CSS bundle, taking into account I could have used all kinds of ways to represent colors, (e.g. RGB/HEX, HSL, and named)?

Thanks

Comment: try https://cssstats.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cssstats.com](http://cssstats.com) suggested above by @teo-dragovic does what I need